# Bytes of memory in the entire program

Tags: assembly, masm

Hey guys I have a quick question. I was hoping for an explanation on how to go about doing this type of question.

Suppose that a program's data and executable code require 1024 bytes of memory. A new section of code must be added; it will be used with various values 39 times during the execution of a program. When implemented as a macro, the macro code requires 74 bytes of memory. When implemented as a procedure, the procedure code requires 104 bytes (including parameter-passing, etc.), and each procedure call requires 9 bytes.

Questions such as these will usually ask, How many bytes of memory will the entire program require if the new code is added as a ___ (macro or procedure).

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Seems like basic arithmetic to me, unless there's some additional information that you forgot to disclose.

Comment: No that would be it. The thing is I can't find anything in my book about this. I realize it is probably quite simple. But I do not know what to add subtract mult etc.

Comment: The fixed cost is X, and then there's a per-use cost of Y, and you've got Z uses. How much is that? Now substitute X, Y and Z for their actual values since you've been given those.

Comment: Alright thanks I'll apply that.

Answer (score 2):

proc: 1024 + (39 * 9) + 104 = 1479
macro: 1024 + (39 *74) = 3910

Comment: I appreciate the help. It seems really silly of me to ask after seeing how to do it haha. But I didn't realize at first. Thank you.

Comment: think of it as you only need the code for the proc once, but you have to call it many times. With the macro every time you want to use the code the entire code has to be reinserted.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate it!